# How to integrate java, log4j, nxlog, loggly in a Windows system?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, loggly

I want to integrate my java desktop application running in Windows with Loggly. I have created an account in Loggly. I have installed nxlog and started the service.

Nxlog.log file shows:

`2014-10-22 19:02:16 INFO nxlog-ce-2.8.1248 started
 2014-10-22 19:02:16 INFO connecting to logs-01.loggly.com:6514
 2014-10-22 19:02:17 INFO successfully connected to logs-01.loggly.com:6514`

I have integrated my java application with log4j as:

```
<appender name="socketappender" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender">
    <param name="Port" value="6514"/>
    <param name="RemoteHost" value="logs-01.loggly.com"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="TRACE"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss} MYAPP: %-5p %m%n"/>
    </layout>            
</appender>
```

Windows logs are showing in Loggly but my java application logs are not found in Loggly. What else I have to do so that my application logs will be routed to Loggly?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable UDP input on nxlog and route it to loggly?  http://nxlog-ce.sourceforge.net/nxlog-docs/en/nxlog-reference-manual.html#im_udp

```
<Input in>
    Module  im_udp
    Port    6514
</Input>
```